# How do crypto games make users not pay gas

Tags: gas, bsc, games

I am researching blockchain games, such as Axie Infinity, Crypto Cars, etc.

As I understand it, when connecting a website to the ethereum/BSC blockchain to submit a transaction, the user will have to pay gas fees.

However, in crypto cars, the user is able to take part in a race, which uses a car NFT to generate CARS tokens, according to a pseudo random algo.

To implement such a mechanism in ethereum/BSC, this car race would need to be the submission of a transaction to the blockchain, which would pay gas fees. However, when playing the game, we pay no gas feed whatsoever to take part in a race.

Does anyone know how the game implements this kind of feature? It would be extremelly interesting for a bunch of dapps to be able to implement this feature (https://cryptocars.me/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i cannot play the game to test it but here is my understanding of such systems.

Only read calls to blockchain are gas less, i.e they dont require any gas, if you're writing data to blockchain you are going to pay the gas, if there is an app that doesn't require gas for some of actions that would be because part of their system is off-chain.

They are running some centralized backend service that is recording your steps and will write to blockchain when it feels necessary.

so to summarize, any action that don't use gas is off-chain